# Unity mouse input script with certain function only works once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoldToMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool holdEntered = false;
    private bool heldHeld = false;
    public Transform holdElevator;

    void Update()
    {
        if (heldHeld == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") > 0)
            {
                holdElevator.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") < 0)
            {
                holdElevator.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") > 0)
            {
                holdElevator.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0)
            {
                holdElevator.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            heldHeld = false;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        holdEntered = true;
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            heldHeld = true;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        holdEntered = false;
    }
}
```

So what i am trying to do is so that when i hold down mouse button after looking at the object this script is attached to the object "holdElevator" should move with the mouse (which it does) and when i release it, it stops (like i want) but the problem is this only works once, how do i fix this?

Comment: ok so heldheld gets set to false every update itteration if the left mousebutton is down. not the 1 time it goes down.... and irrelevant of anything else in the world. heldheld gets set true only if the mousebutton is down when you enter... if its not.. then it wont work at all

Comment: that was what i thought too but where should i put it so it will work more than one time?

Comment: well.. what is the point of holdentered? not going to write it for you but write down on paper - not in your head, physically write instructions on how you would know as a human and what you want.. then have a brew, come back, and try and turn that to code

Comment: holdentered is just so that i can have several of these with different variable names so for instance i can only move the "holdElevator" when i look at this one (and if i don't look at it until i stop holding LMB) and not when i look anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
void OnMouseEnter()
{
    holdEntered = true;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        heldHeld = true;
    }
}
```

Is the problem. It's called when the mouse enters something. You want to do that when the mouse is **over** that thing. Perhaps `OnMouseOver` will work?